# Propositions based on Legendre's symbol

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Let be $n$ an odd integer and $b$ such as $b$ and $n$ are coprimes (*i.e*. $b \wedge n = 1$).

1. If $n$ is divisible by the square of a prime $p$, determine how to find an integer $b$ such as $b \wedge n = 1$ and $b^{(n-1)/2} \not \equiv \pm 1\mod n$.

   - We have $n = kp^2$ and we want $b \wedge n = 1$, *i.e.*  $b \wedge k = 1$ and $b \wedge p = 1$. But we also want $b^{(n-1)/2} \not \equiv \pm 1\mod n$, and $b^{(n-1)/2} \equiv (\frac{b}{n}) \mod n$ so it would mean that $(\frac{b}{n}) = 0$, *i.e.* $b | n$... **What am I misunderstanding here?**
2. If $n = pq$ with $p$ and $q$ two distincts primes and $a$ an integer such as $(\frac{a}{n}) = -1$ and $a \equiv 1 \mod q$. Determine that the relation $(\frac{b}{n}) \equiv b^{(n-1)/2} \mod n$ is false for a such $a$. Prove that a such $a$ still exists.

   - Here we can start by saying that $(\frac{a}{n}) = -1$ because $(\frac{a}{p}) = -1$ and $(\frac{a}{q}) = 1$. **But then how to prove that $b^{(n-1)/2} \not \equiv -1\mod n$?**

Comment: Euler's criterion is relevant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion

Comment: When $n$ is not prime, it is **not** the case that $(b/n)\equiv b^{(n-1)/2}\pmod n$.